# Property change onmousedown not working with multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I've tried to simplify the code as much as possible. What I'm trying to do is implement a way to resize some elements. To do so, I create a `<div class="resize-on">` (it's the orange colored one) and then if you click and hold your mouse down and move then some action should happen like so

```js
var Ui = {};

Ui.Resizer = function (element) {

    this.isResizing = false;

    this.element = element;

    this.resizer = document.createElement("div");
    this.resizer.classList.add('resize-on');
    var toWrap = this.element;
    var parent = toWrap.parentNode;
    var next = toWrap.nextSibling;
    this.resizer.appendChild(toWrap);
    parent.insertBefore(this.resizer, next);
  
   this.resizer.onmousedown = function(event) {
        this.isResizing = true;
        console.log('onmousedown', this.isResizing);
    }.bind(this);

    document.querySelector("body").onmousemove = function(event) {
        if(this.isResizing) {
            console.log('onmousemove', this.isResizing);
        }
    }.bind(this);
    
    document.querySelector("body").onmouseup = function(event) {
        this.isResizing = false;
        console.log('mouse up');
    }.bind(this);
};


(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.resizable'),
        function (element) {
            new Ui.Resizer(
                element
            );
        }
    );
})();
```

```css
.resize-on {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two resizable">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
    <div class="five">five</div>
</div>
```

So this works fine.

Now the problem is if I have multiple `resizable` elements it does not work. It then only works on the "last" one (in this case `<div class="four resizable">four</div>`) Why is that?

The element `<div class="two resizable">two</div>` get's the mousedown but does not show the `onmousemove` anymore.

It's the exact same code as above. Just added the `resizable` class to another HTML element. I can't understand why this doesn't work. Can anyone shed some light on this? Also what do I have to change to get it to work?

```js
var Ui = {};

Ui.Resizer = function (element) {

    this.isResizing = false;

    this.element = element;

    this.resizer = document.createElement("div");
    this.resizer.classList.add('resize-on');
    var toWrap = this.element;
    var parent = toWrap.parentNode;
    var next = toWrap.nextSibling;
    this.resizer.appendChild(toWrap);
    parent.insertBefore(this.resizer, next);

   this.resizer.onmousedown = function(event) {
        this.isResizing = true;
        console.log('onmousedown', this.isResizing);
    }.bind(this);

    document.querySelector("body").onmousemove = function(event) {
        if(this.isResizing) {
            console.log('onmousemove', this.isResizing);
        }
    }.bind(this);

    document.querySelector("body").onmouseup = function(event) {
        this.isResizing = false;
        console.log('mouse up');
    }.bind(this);
};


(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.resizable'),
        function (element) {
            new Ui.Resizer(
                element
            );
        }
    );
})();
```

```css
.resize-on {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two resizable">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four resizable">four</div>
    <div class="five">five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually binding is correct, but with `on...` you can add only a single listener, hence the last listener is the only-one listened in `body` ... To add multiple event listeners, use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Oooh @Teemu that makes sense! You're my hero if that is true, will try right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addEventListener` for the events. Using the property `onmousemove` and others on the body element is only going to allow you to add a single event listener, as the previous one is going to be overwritten, hence why only the last one done, in this case the one for "four", works.

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    this.isResizing = false;
    console.log('mouse up');
}.bind(this);
```

Though you can make it so you only need to set a single listener with only a little modification.

```
Ui.Resizer = function(element){
     //...other code
     this.resizer.onmousedown = function(event) {
        //Set a property on Ui for use to know which Resizer is active and 
        //access it in the body events.
        Ui.active = this;
     }.bind(this);
     //...rest of code excluding body events (mousemove, mouseup)
};
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
   if(Ui.active){
      //if Ui.active is set, active will be the Resizer instance
      //and therefore can access the element it was created for
      //by using active.element
      console.log("mousemove",Ui.active.element);
   }
});
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup",function(event){
   if(Ui.active){
      console.log("mouseup",Ui.active.element);
      //clear active 
      Ui.active = null;
   }
});
```

Demo

```js
var Ui = {};

Ui.Resizer = function(element) {
  this.isResizing = false;

  this.element = element;

  this.resizer = document.createElement("div");
  this.resizer.classList.add('resize-on');
  var toWrap = this.element;
  var parent = toWrap.parentNode;
  var next = toWrap.nextSibling;
  this.resizer.appendChild(toWrap);
  parent.insertBefore(this.resizer, next);
  this.resizer.onmousedown = function(event) {
    //Set a property on Ui for use to know which Resizer is active and 
    //access it in the body events.
    Ui.active = this;
  }.bind(this);
};
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (Ui.active) {
    //if Ui.active is set, active will be the Resizer instance
    //and therefore can access the element it was created for
    //by using active.element
    console.log("mousemove", Ui.active.element);
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  if (Ui.active) {
    console.log("mouseup", Ui.active.element);
    //clear active 
    Ui.active = null;
  }
});

(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.resizable'),
        function (element) {
            new Ui.Resizer(
                element
            );
        }
    );
})();
```

```css
.resize-on {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two resizable">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four resizable">four</div>
    <div class="five">five</div>
</div>
```